# Psalms 111 and 112 and "hal'lu[k]ah"

Tags: minhag, shabbat, tehilim-psalms, mincha-afternoon-prayer

During *mincha* on *Shabas*, many people say psalms [111](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26b1.htm) and [112](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26b2.htm). I've seen them posted on the walls of some synagogues, in fact; one such copy that I've seen has the word "*hal'lu[k]ah*" appended to the end of 112. I've also heard people say the psalms with that word appended to the end of 112. Does anyone know of a source for adding this word, or a reason for doing so?

Comment: [Pesachim 117a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=117&format=pdf) and it is confirmed by manuscript evidence. So I can think of reasons _not_ to append the word :)

Comment: Any idea in which communities/traditions this custom might be found?

Comment: @DoubleAA, re "which communities/traditions": not really. In general AFAICT the psalms are said in _nusach S'farad_ I **think**, which generally (but not exactly) corresponds to _chasidim_. More specific than that I can't get. (And I'm not even sure the psalms are specific to _nusach S'farad_, which is why I didn't use [that tag](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-sefard).)

Comment: Sefardim say 111 after Kadish Titkabal before Kadish Yatom. I've never seen 112 though.

Comment: hmmmm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah#Haftarot_on_Sabbath_afternoon